# What AWS RDS event category subscriptions is for DB updates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-sns

I'm trying to be notified anytime someone creates or delete a row for a RDS cluster. After reading this documentation, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.Messages.html , it's not clear what event category will notify me anytime a create or delete is executed.  Anyone has experience configuring this?

Comment: I want to be notified of deletes but the goal here is to be notified when a new entry is added to the DB so an action can be performed from that.

Answer (score 0):

> it's not clear what event category will notify me anytime a create or delete is executed.

Such category does not exist. You have to implement such solution yourself. One such solution is described in [AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/stream-changes-from-amazon-rds-for-postgresql-using-amazon-kinesis-data-streams-and-aws-lambda/).